# Can I use "gehen" to describe a toddler's walking?

Tags: verb-choice, verb-usage

Meine jüngste Tochter liebt es sehr, die Treppe herunter/ hinunter zu `gehen`.

My youngest daughter likes to go up and down the stairs.

I don't know if `gehen` is more accurate to describe a baby's walking.

Comment: If she's walking, she's walking. No need to take another word just because it's a baby. However, depending on how she moves forward there are certainly different words to tell that. Same applies to English.

Comment: How old is the child? Is she walking properly on two legs in an upright position (asking because you used **baby** in the title). Options may include [krabbeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/krabbeln)(crawling on all fours, baby mode) and [klettern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/klettern)(climbing, using hands to pull herself up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. "Gehen" means "to walk" with all the different meanings, i.e. moving forward in an upright position on two legs. Same as in English, actually (for once).